# how to take duplicate configurations out in filebeat.yaml

Tags: yaml, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I have a list of inputs in filebeat, for example

```
- path: /xxx/xx.log
  enabled: true
  type: log
  fields:
    topic: topic_1

- path: /xxx/ss.log
  enabled: true
  type: log
  fields:
    topic: topic_2
```

so can I take the duplicate configs out as a reference variable? for example

```
- path: /xxx/xx.log
  ${vars}
  fields:
    topic: topic_1

- path: /xxx/ss.log
  ${vars}
  fields:
    topic: topic_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use YAML's inheritance : your first input is used as a model, and the others can override parameters.

```
- &default-log
  path: /xxx/xx.log
  enabled: true
  type: log
  fields:
    topic: topic_1

- <<: *default-log
  path: /xxx/ss.log
  fields:
    topic: topic_2
```

AFAIK there is no way to define an "abstract" default, meaning your `&default-log` should be one of your inputs (not just an abstract model).

(YAML syntax verified with [YAMLlint](http://www.yamllint.com/))